# Login Loop after trying to install AMD catalyst proprietary driver on 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, login, catalyst

I am new to Ubuntu, unfortunately i made the error of installing the wrong driver for catalyst, and it didnt support my card.  I uninstalled as per the wiki, but after that, trying to reinstall the old packages, it can't ocate the ones that are suggested, i used the purge command and then the update / upgrade, so i think it should be ok now, however i get to the log in screen, and when i enter my password, it loops back to the login screen.  I am able to login via ctrl-alt-f2 on the command line.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I countered this problem too. Help me at follow page :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/918359/cant-login-ubuntu-14-04-5-lts-after-installing-amd-ati-driver
Thank you s